# command showing its execution log when I run in Linux machine but when I trigger same command over ssh its not displaying log

Tags: linux, maven, tfs, fortify

When I run following command in putty in its showing execution log as below

```
sourceanalyzer -b sample mvn com.fortify.sca.plugins.maven:sca-maven-plugin:18.10:translate

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.test:sample:jar:0.0.5-SNAPSHOT`
----------
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ line 159, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 155, column 12
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
```

When I run same command over ssh task in TFS, that above execution log is not displaying & getting output as below.

```
2019-01-31T17:48:41.2940860Z sourceanalyzer -b sample mvn com.fortify.sca.plugins.maven:sca-maven-plugin:18.10:translate
2019-01-31T17:48:42.2004980Z ##[section]Finishing: Fortify scanning
```

I am looking to get the output same as in first step in TFS build.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be to pipe the command's output to a text file.

```
[Fortify_command] > outputfile.txt
```